# can't import import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android, eclipse, import, google-cloud-messaging

guys i have a huge problem here. i have a project that uses gcm but the import can't be resolved. I've tried all other suggestion on this site and others but nothing seems to work. please help
I've downloaded the library copied the jar into my /libs folder and added it to build path

but i still got an error on the import

what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you please post your error stack trace.

Comment: sorry, I don't now where to find it...

Comment: You can get it from LogCat. I guess you are using Eclipse.

Comment: yes but I'm pretty new to eclipse. can you be more precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first delete google play services from eclipse and clean project

For google play services first install Google play Services

SDK Manager -> Extras -> Google play Services

after installing go to

File->import->your SDK folder path ->extras->extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Make sure gcm.jar is exist on your adt

/Users/SS/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130717/sdk/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/dist

Comment: I've already do this stuff...however I re-done it but nothing changes. I've android.jar instead of gcm.jar in extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/

Comment: copy android.jar from directory folder and past it into lib @JacopoGrassi

Comment: @JacopoGrassi did you clean your project after doing this...save all file, delete R.java from gen folder and clean your project. and what is android.jar   
is it custom.???also check this is google-play-services.jar is in the path /Users/SS/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130717/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs

Comment: looks like the /dist folder doesn't exist in my sdk....so i've re-dowloaded all and it appeared. solved the import problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

The key point is that you must reference the library—simply adding a .jar file to your Eclipse project will not work. You must follow the directions for referencing a library, or your app won't be able to access the library's resources, and it won't run properly. If you're using Android Studio, this is the string to add to the dependency section of your application's build.gradle file:

> dependencies {    compile:
>   "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+" }

Answer (score 0):

Add GCM.jar in your project from Properties.