# Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (has extras) } U=0: not found

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the registration id of a device (testing using the emulator) to set up push notifications using GCM.

I have tried the following code, which gives me the following error:

```
 Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.pushnotifications"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <permission android:name="com.me.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.me.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="com.me.pushnotifications.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.me.pushnotifications"/>
        </intent-filter>

        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name="com.me.pushnotifications.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to achieve the purpose:

```
package com.me.pushnotifications;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("action::",action);
        try{
            if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")){
                String regId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
                String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
                String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");
                Log.i("regId::",regId);
            }
            else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
                String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
                Log.i("data::",data);
            }
        }
        finally{

        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.me.pushnotifications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        final String appId = getResources().getString(R.string.appId) ;
        Log.i("appName::",appId);
        Button activateButton,deactivateButton;
        activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activateButton);
        deactivateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deactivateButton);

        activateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("activate::","clicked");
                Intent regIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
                Log.i("intent::","created");
                regIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        new Intent(), 0));
regIntent.putExtra("sender", "registration_id");
                startService(regIntent);
            }
        });

        deactivateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("deactivate::","clicked");
                Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
                Log.i("intent::","created");
                unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        new Intent(), 0));
                startService(unregIntent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have installed the Google API's for API Level 18. What may be the reason for the issue?

Comment: Where have you declared .GCMIntentService in manifest file??

Comment: am using a BroadcastReceiver instead of GCMIntentService

Comment: Check this : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: When do you get that error? Can you include more line from the logcat?

Comment: Try updating google services on your device @Gaurav Sood

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your intent-filter tag in manifest 
 file

```
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

Like this

```
<intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: @user2739737 did you import gcm.jar from ectras folder from adt.if no then first go to install google play service goto android SDk manager->extras->Google Play Services 
then put gcm.jar file to your lib folder (/Users/SS/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130717/sdk/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/dist) gcm.jar path
clean your project then run

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678787/cant-import-import-com-google-android-gcm-gcmbaseintentservice/19678841#19678841 check this also

Comment: i have imported gcm jar into libs. still does not seem to work

Comment: @user2739737 com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER replace this instead of it com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.gcmclient.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />

        <category android:name="com.example.gcmclient" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.example.gcmclient.GcmMessageHandler" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```